# Calling 'confess' under Plack/Starman

Tags: perl, plack, carp, starman

I have a Plack/Starman application running with TryCatch statements that call 'confess' from the Carp module. However I notice that the confess output is not printing to STDOUT. I've tried routing STDERR output to STDOUT '2>&1', but still don't see anything. I have search for possible error log files with no luck. Where in the world is this printing to? I am sure it's probably a simple answer. Where are the log files located? I am running on a Ubuntu box if that matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some confusion here. First, `confess` (and all the other carps in the pond) don't print to STDOUT: they print to STDERR. Second, you're stopping the exception and hence the associated output using `try/catch` (glorified `eval`), so it's not printed unless you explicitly print it yourself. You'll see warnings, but you won't see messages of instructions that would terminate the program (well, not Plack, but your script) because they're swallowed by your try/catch code and it's up to you to decide whether any of it should be printed and where to.

- https://metacpan.org/module/Carp
- https://metacpan.org/module/TryCatch
- https://metacpan.org/module/Plack